# How to access functions called from StandardGeneric?

Tags: r

I am trying to correct a small error in a R package. My problem is that the function I would like to modify is called through standardGeneric instance. I tried to trace the function :

```
trace('regFit', edit=TRUE)
```

But it does not display the actual function content. Would you know how I can access it?

Comment: in a console you can run `grep -R regFit your-package-directory` to find the files that contain the word `regFit`. It is likely in the `R/` directory.

Answer (score 0):

If you run `debug(regFit)`, then single step into the function using `n`, it should step into the method being used on the 2nd or 3rd step.

Comment: I tried doing this but I get an object not found error message :/